# How do GA collect network provider's information?

Tags: google-analytics

How could GA gather network provider's name?

For example, I can see `china unicom jiangxi province network` in my report. That is quite detailed. How did GA achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr- Google uses the name of the organization which has been assigned the IP address the visitor is visiting with

IP Addresses are issued to internet service providers in "Blocks" by [Regional Internet Registries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry). In case case of the IP address you're seeing, the ISP `china unicom jiangxi province network` requested and manages the IP address of the visitor and because that ownership is public Google Analytics is able to link the IP address to the ISP.

You can actually find the owner of any IP address by running a whois against the IP address.

For example, if you wanted to find out the owner of Google's Public DNS IP you could run `whois 8.8.8.8`, which would (as of January 2nd 2014) return

```
Level 3 Communications, Inc. LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1) 8.0.0.0 - 8.255.255.255
Google Incorporated LVLT-GOOGL-1-8-8-8 (NET-8-8-8-0-1) 8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255
```

This case is a bit complex, but you'll find that `Level 3 Communications, Inc.` manages all IP addresses between `8.0.0.0` and `8.255.255.255` (considered a /8 block, which contains 16 million records), but Level 3 has publicly assigned `Google Incorporated` the addresses between `8.8.8.0`-`8.8.8.255` (considered a /24 block, which contains 256 IP addresses)

If a visitor with the address `8.8.8.8` visited your site, Google would list the ISP as `Google Incorporated`

Comment: Hi, where did you go to find the range of IPs?

Comment: A standard `whois 8.8.8.8` will include the ranges. But you can also check out http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=8.8.8.8?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2